How to understanc MavenPublication in syntax
when i read doc:https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/maven/MavenPublication.html. i saw content blow.

A MavenPublication is the representation/configuration of how Gradle
should publish something in Maven format. You directly add a named
Maven publication the project's publishing.publications container by
providing MavenPublication as the type.
 publishing {
   publications {
     myPublicationName(MavenPublication) {
       // Configure the publication here
     }
   }
 }


the part
 myPublicationName(MavenPublication) {
    // Configure the publication here
} 

syntax is very confusion.  myPublicationName is not like a variable, also not like closure，also not like method, what should i understand in syntax.

There is a full example in the documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html#N1C0D1

It is a method invocation.  This is "short-hand" for `myPublicationName(MavenPublication, { ... })

yeah.it make sense. but if myPublicationName is a method invocation, where the method defined? is't name just casual. @cfrick

It's not defined. You just defined it (see how groovy can deal with missing methods)

The syntax is known as domain-specific language (DSL). Specifically the example you are referencing, that is the Groovy DSL. As the name indicates, it is a DSL written using the Groovy language.
Know that Gradle's core APIs are written using plain Java, but the implement a variety of Groovy specific APIs such as GroovyObjectSupport.
Modern versions of Gradle provide an alternative DSL: Kotlin DSL. As the name indicates, it is a DSL written using the Kotlin language.
Which one you use is a matter of preference. However, the recommended and default DSL for Gradle is the Kotlin DSL: https://blog.gradle.org/kotlin-dsl-is-now-the-default-for-new-gradle-builds
Back to your example, myPublicationName in plain Java is:
PublishingExtension publishing = project.getExtensions().getByType(PublishingExtension.class);
publishing.getPublications().create("myPublicationName", MavenPublication.class, publication -> {})

In the Groovy world, you can ommit the get portion which then becomes publishing.publications. Gradle provides a convenient method on the PublishingExtension type:
void publications(Action<? super PublicationContainer> configure);

This allows:
publishing {
    publications { // the convenient method

    }
}

You can then see that the scope of 'this' within that Action is PublicationContainer which then allows you to create publications by either explicitly calling the create method as shown above, or by using Groovy specific idioms Gradle provides, in this case, calling a method that does not exist calls create behind the scenes using the method name as the publication name.
